# How to create pads with a lot of emotion in them?

Tags: sound-design

Examples are:

- Pad on the background
- two pads

I was wondering what the basis is for these sounds. I don't exactly want to replicate them, but knowing how this is constructed gives me chance to experiment a little bit on my Blofeld. And it goes a lot better when you have some knowledge beforehand, right? How to create that vocal sound is a lot interesting in the Traumprinz track.

Comment: Why are people so adamant on trying to describe sound with horribly abstract terminology that is rarely interpreted the same from person to person. Once you figure out how to make emotional pads, please help me make screaming leads, and phat bass.....

Comment: It does matter. Being able to objectively describe something makes things a whole lot easier. "Emotional pad" mean dick all to anyone.

Comment: I'd have to agree with Scott here. Neither of those two tracks appear to have anything I'd call emotional in them, probably because my taste in music is different to yours. You need to describe what you mean.

Comment: I've used the term from someone else who had the same question about the same music on a forum. For me this was a logical way to explain it since I couldn't formulate it on any other way. But you're right that everyone is having their own perspective on sound and music so I'll take your advise and try to be more clear with my words next time.

Answer (score 2):

I think its really about the reverb & cutoff, and the movement of the pad with respect to cutoff, amp, and such.  Slow attack on amp and env and plus a lowpass filter (or band pass will work too, but I personally prefer to lowpass then just eq out the bottom how I see fit, because it's easier to expand the sound later using modulation) makes the sound pretty chill and emotional.  For the most part these are supersaws, but you can explore w/ adding higher pitched triangles (or sines?) to give it that really high sound from like the first one (also explore with cutoff movement using lfos and envs).  If you want (this is not in the sound btw) you can also add a tiny bit of lfo to the pitch to give it a bit of analogue style pitch drift, which can sound pretty emotional too.

Comment: Thanks, what do you mean exactly with expanding the sound with modulation? That i'll add something else later on with low end? Another seperate sound? I'll let you guys hear the example soon based on your tip

Comment: I agree, but I would add that the right amount of tremolo can also help with the movement as well as detuned waves.

Comment: Yea detune the waves, thats the point of a supersaw.  By expanding the sound I meant letting more frequencies pass with your filter (or eq < changing your eq settings).  I feel this gives more flexibility than a band pass.

Answer (score 1):

The pad in the first track may be based on a super stretched out sample before applying effects (filter, sidechained compressor, reverb), not a synth at all. or it could be a combination of each.  When the beat cuts out it seems particularly clear that part of the pad is a very slowed down vocal sound.  That could give the graininess and richness that makes it distinctive.  Also keep in mind that there is a chord created by the various tones within this sound even if they may initially read as just overtones, they are deliberately structured to create an emotional harmonic quality.

Comment: The second track also utilizes chords within the pads, a simple alternation between a major chord on the higher note and a minor chord answering it.

Answer (score 0):

For the first one, **a lot of reverb** is what is mostly doing the "emotional" sensation.
To recreate it I would take a snare sample, cut the high with an enveloppe on a lowpass filter and send the whole thing into a reverb.

for the second one an enveloppe with a really short decay on a basic waveform (like a saw but not a sinewave) should be good enough as a starting point.

Comment: Thanks, cool trick with the snare example. Im gonna try that out and some other stuff i can find. Cheers m8